# Visual Studio 2010 @ High DPI

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dpi

I know this has been asked before but I will ask it again.

I'm having issues on my Visual Studio 2010 in a High DPI 1920x1080 display, I already tried the Registry Fixed but seems not to work. I know I'm using a very later version of VS but this is the only way to battle compatibility on lower version of Windows.

What method should I use? Should I switch to VS2015, or is there any other way around to fix this.

**Design Time**

[image]

**Run Time**

[image]

Comment: What is the specific issue? Is it the placement of the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a DPI issue. Your buttons' `Anchor` property is set to `Bottom, Right`. This will cause them to follow the *bottom* of the form when it is resized. If the grid control below them is anchored to the top it will remain in the same position, but the buttons are moved over/away from it in order to always remain a certain distance from the bottom.

Set the `Anchor` for your buttons to `Top, Right` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid and hasty. I didn't see that the Anchor Property was set to Bottom, Right. Thank you for pointing that out. I'm LOL!!!

Comment: @ardiepagulayan : Glad I could help! Happy coding!